# Laravel - simpliest elseif

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
@foreach ($todos as $todo)
@if($todo->is_completed == 1)
    <tr class="bg-success">
@elseif($todo->level == 1)
    <tr class="bg-primary">
@elseif($todo->level == 2)
    <tr class="bg-warning">
@elseif($todo->level == 3)
    <tr class="bg-danger">
@endif
```

Hi, have i to do it more simple or its a normal practice?

Comment: You may use switch, which can make it slightly simpler.

Comment: I think switch would come out at even more verbiage, once you've included the break; for each case.

Comment: use Switch statement `@switch, @case, @break`. Refer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#switch-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using if-else, I would recommend you to use [switch](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#switch-statements) statement.

```
@foreach ($todos as $todo)
   @if($todo->is_completed == 1)
     <tr class="bg-success">
   @endif

   $level= $todo->level;

  @switch($level)
       @case('1')
           <tr class="bg-primary">
       @break
 
       @case('2')
            <tr class="bg-warning">
       @break
 
       @case('3')
            <tr class="bg-danger">
       @break
  @endswitch
```

Comment: I had to delete $level variable and i've putted IF at the end. Works, but is that correct?